# Drop database sometimes fails when using FILESTREAM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) and have databases using FILESTREAM feature which will store data into separate files for certain columns.
Database looks like:

```
CREATE DATABASE [MyDatabase]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
    ADD FILEGROUP [FileStreamDataFileGroup] CONTAINS FILESTREAM 
GO

ALTER DATABASE [MyDatabase] 
    ADD FILE ( NAME = N'MyDatabase_FileStreamData', 
               FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData'
             ) TO FILEGROUP [FileStreamDataFileGroup]
GO

CREATE TABLE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] 
(
    [Id]      BIGINT           NOT NULL,
    [DataId]  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [Content] VARBINARY (MAX)  FILESTREAM NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__PredictionModel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([DataId] ASC)
) FILESTREAM_ON [FileStreamDataFileGroup];
GO
```

I run tests which constantly creates new databases, run tests and drop them afterwards.
SQL server is on heavy load because tests run in parallel on multiple databases.
In some rare cases (<1%) drop of database fails with error:

> Could not delete file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData'. See the SQL Server error log for more information.

SQL Server logs shows follow logs:

> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is Denied)' while attempting 'StreamFileMgr::DoDeleteFsFile' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData' at 'stmfilemgr.cpp'(5314).
>
> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is Denied)' while attempting 'RemoveDirectory' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData\8a803ce2-3e97-4d60-8aa1-e704d858aae9\c802f11a-9c13-4040-9e53-bcd3c67b7960' at 'storage.cpp'(851).
>
> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is Denied)' while attempting 'RemoveDirectory' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData\8a803ce2-3e97-4d60-8aa1-e704d858aae9\c802f11a-9c13-4040-9e53-bcd3c67b7960' at 'storage.cpp'(851).
>
> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is Denied)' while attempting 'RemoveDirectory' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData\8a803ce2-3e97-4d60-8aa1-e704d858aae9\c802f11a-9c13-4040-9e53-bcd3c67b7960' at 'storage.cpp'(851).
>
> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is Denied)' while attempting 'RemoveDirectory' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData\8a803ce2-3e97-4d60-8aa1-e704d858aae9\c802f11a-9c13-4040-9e53-bcd3c67b7960' at 'storage.cpp'(851).

The database itself is really gone (`.mdf` and `.ldf` files are deleted) but the folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA\MyDatabase-FileStreamData` still exists.

This is kind of an inconsistent state and hard to workaround because no other than SQL Server service user can access it and delete it.

Does anyone has some hints what went wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: Most probably, something other than SQL Server has managed to grab an open handle to the file folder -- Explorer, the Windows Search index service, an antivirus program, what have you. This is supposed to be made as unlikely as possible by SQL Server setting appropriate permissions, but that still doesn't stop everything with administrative permissions. You can use Process Explorer to look for open handles and/or Process Monitor for who's opening handles if they're too transient.